# How to find the order of these groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I don't know why but I just cannot see how to find the orders of these groups:

$YXY^{-1}=X^2$

$YXY^{-1}=X^4$

$YXY^{-1}=X^3$

With the property that $X^5 = 1$ and $Y^4 =1$

How would I go about finding the order? The questions asks me to find which of these groups are isomorphic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You should treat those relations as a rule on how to commute $Y$ past $X$, for example the first can be written:
$$YX = X^2Y$$
Then you know that every element can be written in the form $X^nY^m$ for some $n$ and $m$.  Use the orders of $X$ and $Y$ to figure out how many elements there are of this form.

Comment: Can you help with say an example of this done on the first group? I'm still struggling to understand this. Won't it take quite a long time to commute all the possible elements?

Comment: @Lolwat You don't need to commute all the possible elements - you just need to understand how powers of Y move to the right past powers of X.